# Why printing result are different from function

Tags: python

Here is my function from Python:

```
def Ggen(word):
     result = []
     while(len(word)!=1):
         a = word.pop()
         b = word
         temp = (a,b)
         print temp
         result.append(temp)
     return result
```

Assume I have data call `test =  ['f','c','a','m','p']`.

My result generated from `print` in function is:

```
('p', ['f', 'c', 'a', 'm'])
('m', ['f', 'c', 'a'])
('a', ['f', 'c'])
('c', ['f'])
```

But if I run `Ggen(test)` I got this instead:

```
[('p', ['f']), ('m', ['f']), ('a', ['f']), ('c', ['f'])]
```

What happen to my code. Is anyone how to get similar result from above?

Comment: `b = word`... Just think about that. What is `word`?

Comment: Lists are mutable. You are mutating the list in the loop. You are printing them before you mutate them, but are returning a final value which has been thoroughly mutated. Why not make copies of the list at various stages if you want to preserve the unmutated versions from earlier in the loop? As it is, you are just creating a whole bunch of aliases for the same list.

Comment: word is just a list of element. My algorithm was pop the list each time and create a (key,value) where key is pop() data while value is the remaining data in list. I keep repeat until like the result as the print should be

Answer (score 4):

Everytime you `word.pop()` you are changing the *reference* of the list that is contained within `result`. So, you are printing the intermediate values, but what you finally return is going to be the `word` list that exited the while loop.

If you would like to return what you see being printed, you need to make a copy of the list each time you `pop` from it.

```
def Ggen(word):
    result = []
    while(len(word)!=1):
        result.append((word.pop(),word[:]))
    return result
```